# Reading and writing into a file in fortran95

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I am trying to do the following in Fortran:

1. Read a text document line by line
2. Encode each line word by word by "exchanging" each letter by the
   one that comes  l places after it in the alphabet, l= length of the
   word
3. Write the encoded line into a new output document

My loop seems to run indefinitely and no words are being written into the output documents

My test input document is just 2 lines:

- some stuff
- some more stuff

The first line is being read and encoded correctly

```
PROGRAM zeichen
USE PufferMod
IMPLICIT NONE 
CHARACTER(LEN=132) :: z
CHARACTER(maxlen):: x
INTEGER:: a,e,i,l


OPEN(UNIT=39,FILE="intext.txt",ACTION="READ", STATUS="OLD")
OPEN(UNIT=40, FILE="outext.txt", ACTION="WRITE")

DO 
2 READ(39,"(A)", end=10) z
    a=1;
    DO WHILE(a<133)
     WRITE(*,*) z
     WRITE(*,*) a
     CALL Suche_Wort(z,a,e)
         l=e-a+1
         WRITE(*,*) a,e,l
                DO i=a,e
                    IF(z(i:i)/="") THEN
                    CALL Codiere(z(i:i),l)
                    END IF
                END DO
                a=e+1
    END DO 
 WRITE(40,*) z
 END DO
10 CLOSE(UNIT=39)
   CLOSE(UNIT=40)

END PROGRAM zeichen









    MODULE PufferMod
IMPLICIT NONE
PRIVATE
PUBLIC :: maxlen, Codiere, Suche_Wort

INTEGER, PARAMETER :: maxlen = 132

CONTAINS

FUNCTION Kleinbuchstabe(z)
    CHARACTER(LEN=1) :: z
    LOGICAL :: Kleinbuchstabe
    Kleinbuchstabe= "a" <= z .AND. z <= "z"
END FUNCTION Kleinbuchstabe

FUNCTION Grossbuchstabe(z)
    CHARACTER(LEN=1) :: z
    LOGICAL :: Grossbuchstabe
    Grossbuchstabe= "A" <= z .AND. z <= "Z"
END FUNCTION Grossbuchstabe

FUNCTION Buchstabe(z)
    CHARACTER(LEN=1) :: z
    LOGICAL :: Buchstabe
    Buchstabe=  (("a" <= z .AND. z <= "z") .OR. ("A" <= z .AND. z <= "Z"))
END FUNCTION Buchstabe

SUBROUTINE Codiere(z, Verschiebung)
    CHARACTER(LEN=1) :: z
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: Verschiebung
    INTEGER :: CodevonA
    IF ( Kleinbuchstabe(z) ) THEN
    CodevonA= ICHAR("a")
    ELSE IF ( Grossbuchstabe(z) ) THEN
    CodevonA= ICHAR("A")
    END IF
    z= CHAR( CodevonA + MOD( ICHAR(z) - CodevonA + Verschiebung, 26 ) )
END SUBROUTINE Codiere

SUBROUTINE Suche_Wort(z,a,e)
CHARACTER(LEN=maxlen), INTENT(in):: z
INTEGER, INTENT(inout):: a
INTEGER, INTENT(out):: e
CHARACTER:: x, temp*1
INTEGER:: i
i=1
temp=z(a:a)
!WRITE(*,*) "a before loop",a, "temp", temp
 DO WHILE(temp == " ")    !Find start of next word
    temp=z(a+i:a+i)
    i=i+1
    a=a+1
 END DO
 !WRITE(*,*) "a after loop", a
 e=a+1
 i=1
 temp=z(e:e)
DO WHILE(temp/= "")      !find where the word ends by finding a space
    temp=z(e+i:e+i)
    i=i+1
    e=e+1
    IF(temp == " ") EXIT
END DO
END SUBROUTINE Suche_Wort

END MODULE PufferMod
```

Comment: I thought it will end when the last line is read; when the input document ends.

Comment: The 10 is where to go when the input document is fully read.

Comment: When I run your code I get a segmentation fault, when the code walks off the end of `z`.  Try recompiling with error bounds checking switched on and have another go.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You consult your compiler documentation, search for the phrase *array bounds* or *bounds check*.  Or have a look at other questions here on SO, the topic is covered about once a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Suche_Wort` subroutine has at least three issues:

- It never checks if the indices of the `z` variable are within bounds.
- It assumes that the end index is strictly bigger than the start index, therefore not allowing for 1-character words.
- In each of its loops, it increments by one both `i` and the other integer variable (`a` in the first loop, `e` in the second loop), effectively incrementing the index of z by 2 in every iteration.

I would recommend applying two changes to the `zeichen` program in order to get rid of the trailing spaces, by using the intrinsic functions `trim` (remove trailing space) and `len_trim` (compute length of the trimmed variable):

```
2 READ(39,"(A)", end=10) z
    a=1;
    DO WHILE(a<=len_trim(z))
     WRITE(*,*) z
     WRITE(*,*) a
     CALL Suche_Wort(trim(z),a,e)
!...
```

Then, the checks and corrections can be added to the `Suche_Wort` subroutine (more easily than if we had to worry about the possibility that all characters left in `z(a:)` were spaces):

```
SUBROUTINE Suche_Wort(z,a,e)
  CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(in):: z ! Dummy argument has length of actual argument
  INTEGER, INTENT(inout):: a
  INTEGER, INTENT(out):: e
  CHARACTER(len=1):: temp
  temp=z(a:a)
  DO WHILE((temp == " ").and.(a<len(z)))    !Find start of next word
    temp=z(a+1:a+1)
    a=a+1
  END DO
  e=a                              ! Allows 1-character words
  DO WHILE((temp/= " ").and.(e<len(z)))      !find where the word ends by finding a space
    temp=z(e+1:e+1)
    e=e+1
  END DO
END SUBROUTINE Suche_Wort
```

Comment: After applying your changes and a bit more it is working almost perfectly. The only remaining issue is the  output being on the same line

Comment: Sorry that issue only happens in notepad, not in notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to consider words at all ?
Just convert A:Z or a:z.

```
   PROGRAM zeichen
     CHARACTER(LEN=132) :: z
     INTEGER :: iostat, Verschiebung = 1

     OPEN (UNIT=39, FILE="ziechen.f90", ACTION="READ", STATUS="OLD")
     OPEN (UNIT=40, FILE="outext.txt", STATUS="UNKNOWN")

      DO 
         READ (39,fmt="(A)", iostat=iostat) z
         if ( iostat /= 0 ) exit

         call convert_line ( z, Verschiebung )

         WRITE (40,fmt="(A)") trim (z)
         WRITE ( *,fmt="(A)") trim (z)
      END DO
   END PROGRAM zeichen

    Subroutine convert_line ( z, inc )
      character*(*) z
      integer   inc, i
      do i = 1, len_trim (z)
        call convert_character ( z(i:i), inc )
      end do
    end Subroutine convert_line

    Subroutine convert_character ( z, inc )
      character z
      integer   inc, ia, ic
!
      if      ( z >= 'A' .and. z <= 'Z' ) then
        ia = ichar ('A')
      else if ( z >= 'a' .and. z <= 'z' ) then
        ia = ichar ('a')
      else
        return
      end if
      ic = mod ( ichar (z) - ia + inc + 26, 26 )
      z  = char (ia + ic )
!
    end Subroutine convert_character
```

Comment: Because I'm changing each word by it's length and not all by a fixed amount

Comment: My mistake, I took "l" for 1 when reading the code. The change I made for convert_character may have some relevance, depending on the character set available for words.

Comment: I appreciate it anyway; any more well written code is useful for me.

Comment: If you have a `CHARACTER` array `z` containing the word, you can convert it via
   `z = merge(achar(iachar(z)+modulo(iand(iachar(z),NOT(32))-65+size(z),26)-
      (iand(iachar(z),NOT(32))-65)),z,BLT(iand(iachar(z),NOT(32))-65,26))`

Comment: @user5713492 I really don't understand why such a complex solution is appealing. I would always recommend breaking the problem down to smaller pieces that are easier to understand.